# How to determine if three vectors form a basis for a subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

This is a follow up question ( math.stackexchange.com/q/3018473);  i'm  interested in understanding some other part of the problem.

I have three vectors, v1, v2, v4, which are linearly independent.[image]

I need to find the orthonormal basis of their linear span.

[image]

To see if v1 and v2 are orthonormal, I do the dot multiplication using u1 and v2:

(u1,v2)= 0 , as shown in the picture.

Now here is were my question arises. I found u3, which gives me u3=(0,0,1,0).

Since before , to see if u1 and v2 are orthogonal, i found the dot product of (u1,v2), can i do the same thing with v3?

Meaning:

(u3·v1)=0 and (u3·v2)=0? (i check the answers using the same multiplication process in the images)

Practically my question is: since i found the dot product of (u1,v2) to see that they are orthogonal to each other , can i do the dot product of (u3,v1) and (u3,v2) to see if the u3 is orthogonal to v1 and v2?

(u3,v1)= (0,0,1,0)·(1,1,0,0)=0

(u3,v2)=(0,0,1,0)·(1,-1,0,0)=0

Somebody please help?

Comment: Yes, zero dot product of any two non-zero vectors implies they are orthogonal.

Comment: If I may give you a piece of advice, using MathJax really improves the readability of questions. And it if fairly simple to use, for example `$u_1$` translates to $u_1$. Please consider that for your next question

Comment: Please do not delete a question just to post the exact same thing again with a minor change. Look under the question where it says "edit" and use that instead. I was in the midst of answering your question when you deleted it, so this is not just silly behavior, I consider it very inconsiderate as well to the people you are asking for help.

Comment: For reference, the earlier posting of this question (word for word identical) was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018557/how-to-find-orthonormal-basis-of-a-subspace. Before deleting it you complained nobody had answered; well, guess what! **I was in the midst of writing an answer** when you deleted the question and blocked me. That's why I was so annoyed when I wrote the previous comment. I don't think you should try to "fix" any of this now, since you have an answer under this copy of the question, but please follow the guidelines in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, if you have two non-zero vectors ${\bf a}$ and ${\bf b}$ and want to decide whether they are orthogonal, you just need to calculate their inner product (dot product). If it is zero then they are orthogonal

$$
\langle {\bf a} | {\bf b} \rangle  = 0 ~~~{\bf a}\mbox{ and }{\bf b}\mbox{ are orthogonal}
$$

So in your example, $\langle {\bf u}_1 | {\bf v}_2 \rangle = 0$  which means that ${\bf u}_1$ and ${\bf v}_2$ are orthogonal. Now, since $\langle {\bf u}_3 | {\bf v}_1 \rangle = 0$ then ${\bf u}_3$ is also orthogonal to ${\bf v}_1$